# Creación de escenario ns3 con bridge's

Tags: c++

Muy buenas a todos, os comento mi problema a ver si alguien tiene más idea que yo. Estoy haciendo un proyecto en ns3 sobre redes voip para un trabajo de la universidad. El supuesto escenario se basa en 2 sedes en las que habrá un numero `X` e `Y` de teléfonos en cada sede, todos conectados  a un *bridge*, y conectado este a un *Router*. Cada sede tiene un numero `X` de enlaces con el otro *router* con el que se balancea carga y medimos ciertos parámetros estadísticos de las llamadas. El problema surge a la hora de crear el escenario, me está siendo imposible crear una configuración de red en la que un número `X` de teléfonos y un *router* se conectan a un *bridge*. Os dejo el código:

```
Ptr<UniformRandomVariable> varon;
Ptr<UniformRandomVariable> varoff;


//primero creamos los R de salida de cada central
NodeContainer R;
R.Create(2);
//Estos nodos irán unidos por enlaces p2p


//Configuro la topologia p2p
PointToPointHelper p2p;
p2p.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (velocidades[resultado->velocidad]));
p2p.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("2ms"));

//Creo los enlaces p2p entre centrales

NetDeviceContainer Rdevices;

for (uint8_t j=0;j<resultado->enlaces;j++){

    NetDeviceContainer enlaceRouters = p2p.Install (NodeContainer (R.Get(0), R.Get(1) ) );

    Rdevices.Add (enlaceRouters.Get(0));
    Rdevices.Add (enlaceRouters.Get(1));
}




//----Esto seria para las centrales. Ahora los telefonos/bridges
NodeContainer terminales1; //Sede1
NodeContainer terminales2; //Sede 2
terminales1.Create(telef1);
terminales2.Create(telef2);

//Añado el R al nodecontainer de los telefonos para realizar los enlaces despues
terminales1.Add(R.Get(0));
terminales2.Add(R.Get(1));



NodeContainer Bridge1;//Sede 1
Bridge1.Create(1);
NodeContainer Bridge2;//Sede 2
Bridge2.Create(1);

PointToPointHelper p2pInterno;
p2pInterno.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("100Mbps"));
p2pInterno.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("2ms"));

NetDeviceContainer terminales1Devices;
NetDeviceContainer Bridge1Devices;


//Uso telef1+1 porque hemos añadido al NodeContainer de los terminales1 el R.Get(0)
for(uint16_t j=0;j<=telef1;j++){
    NetDeviceContainer enlace1 = p2pInterno.Install (NodeContainer(terminales1.Get (j) ,Bridge1)  );
    terminales1Devices.Add (enlace1.Get(0));
    Bridge1Devices.Add (enlace1.Get(1));
}


NetDeviceContainer terminales2Devices;
NetDeviceContainer Bridge2Devices;
//Uso telef1+1 porque hemos añadido al NodeContainer de los terminales2 el R.Get(1)
for(uint16_t j=0;j<=telef2;j++){
    NetDeviceContainer enlace1 = p2pInterno.Install (NodeContainer(terminales2.Get(j),Bridge2)  );
    terminales2Devices.Add (enlace1.Get(0));
    Bridge2Devices.Add (enlace1.Get(1));
}







//Una vez todos los enlaces creados, instalo el bridge que conmuta paquetes.

Ptr<Node> puente1 = Bridge1.Get(0);
BridgeHelper b1;
b1.Install (puente1, Bridge1Devices);

Ptr<Node> puente2 = Bridge2.Get(0);
BridgeHelper b2;
b2.Install (puente2, Bridge2Devices);

//Añado la pila TCP/IP a los dispositivos
InternetStackHelper stack;

//stack.Install(R); R.get(0) y R.get(1) estan incluidos en terminales, quizas esta linea sobre
stack.Install(terminales1);
stack.Install(terminales2);

Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4;
Ipv4InterfaceContainer telefonosSede1;
ipv4.SetBase ("10.1.0.0","255.255.0.0");
telefonosSede1 = ipv4.Assign (terminales1Devices);

Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4v2;
Ipv4InterfaceContainer telefonosSede2;
ipv4v2.SetBase ("10.2.0.0","255.255.0.0");
telefonosSede2 = ipv4v2.Assign (terminales2Devices);


Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4v3;
Ipv4InterfaceContainer routers;
ipv4v3.SetBase ("10.3.0.0","255.255.255.0");
routers = ipv4v3.Assign (Rdevices);


Ipv4GlobalRoutingHelper::PopulateRoutingTables ();
//Creo aplicacion UDP sumidero y tal.

//Establezco un sumidero de paquetes en cada telefono
//Utilizamos el puerto 5600 para el sumidero
uint16_t port = 5600;
PacketSinkHelper sink ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", Address (InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), port)));


ApplicationContainer sumidero1 = sink.Install(terminales1);
ApplicationContainer sumidero2 = sink.Install(terminales2);

//Creo aplicacion que envia paquetes ON/OFF para simular llamada voip

//Problema con direccionamiento

 OnOffHelper clientes ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory",
                            Address (InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), port)));

ApplicationContainer tx1 = clientes.Install(terminales1);
ApplicationContainer tx2 = clientes.Install(terminales2);



varon=CreateObject<UniformRandomVariable>();
  varon->SetAttribute("Max", DoubleValue(MAXONVOIP));
  varon->SetAttribute("Min", DoubleValue(MINONVOIP));
  varoff=CreateObject<UniformRandomVariable>();
  varoff->SetAttribute("Max", DoubleValue(MAXOFFVOIP));
  varoff->SetAttribute("Min", DoubleValue(MINOFFVOIP));
  //Configuramos la aplicación OnOff
  clientes.SetConstantRate (DataRate ("64kbps"));
  clientes.SetAttribute("OnTime", PointerValue(varon));
  clientes.SetAttribute("OffTime", PointerValue(varoff));



//Cambio de cola de ROUTER 1 (por si hace falta)
PointerValue tmp;
          R.Get(0)->GetObject<NetDevice>()->GetAttribute("TxQueue",tmp);
          Ptr<Object> txQueue = tmp.GetObject();
          Ptr<DropTailQueue> dtq = txQueue->GetObject <DropTailQueue>();
          NS_ASSERT (dtq!=0);
          UintegerValue limit;
          dtq->GetAttribute("MaxPackets",limit);
          NS_LOG_INFO ("Tamaño de la cola del Router 1: "<<limit.Get()<<" paquetes" );
          dtq->SetAttribute("MaxPackets",UintegerValue(100));
          dtq->GetAttribute("MaxPackets",limit);
          NS_LOG_INFO("Tamaño de la cola del Router 1 cambiado a: "<<limit.Get()<<" paquetes");

//Cambio de cola de ROUTER 2 (por si hace falta)
PointerValue tmp2;
          R.Get(1)->GetObject<NetDevice>()->GetAttribute("TxQueue",tmp2);
          Ptr<Object> txQueue2 = tmp2.GetObject();
          Ptr<DropTailQueue> dtq2 = txQueue->GetObject <DropTailQueue>();
          NS_ASSERT (dtq2!=0);
          UintegerValue limit2;
          dtq2->GetAttribute("MaxPackets",limit2);
          NS_LOG_INFO ("Tamaño de la cola del Router 2: "<<limit2.Get()<<" paquetes" );
          dtq2->SetAttribute("MaxPackets",UintegerValue(100));
          dtq2->GetAttribute("MaxPackets",limit2);
          NS_LOG_INFO("Tamaño de la cola del Router 2 cambiado a: "<<limit2.Get()<<" paquetes");



//SUSCRIPCION DE TRAZAS



tx1.Start (Seconds (2.0));
tx2.Start (Seconds (2.0));
tx1.Stop (Seconds (15.0));
tx2.Stop (Seconds (15.0));

Simulator::Run ();
Simulator::Destroy ();
```

Esta parte del código está referida a la creación del escenario. Y el error que ha hecho que venga aquí a realizar esta pregunta es el siguiente:

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-45-211 ns-3.20]$ ./waf --run simvoip
Waf: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/ns-allinone-3.20/ns-3.20/build'
[ 816/2290] cxx: scratch/simvoip/simvoip.cc -> build/scratch/simvoip/simvoip.cc.3.o
[2265/2290] cxxprogram: build/scratch/simvoip/Observador.cc.3.o build/scratch/simvoip/simvoip.cc.3.o -> build/scratch/simvoip/simvoip
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/ns-allinone-3.20/ns-3.20/build'
'build' finished successfully (3.877s)
msg="Device does not support SendFrom: cannot be added to bridge.", file=../src/bridge/model/bridge-net-device.cc, line=251
terminate called without an active exception
Command ['/home/ec2-user/ns-allinone-3.20/ns-3.20/build/scratch/simvoip/simvoip'] terminated with signal SIGIOT. Run it under a debugger to get more information (./waf --run <program> --command-template="gdb --args %s <args>").
```

Dejo tambien la pila del programa, por si sirve:

```
    (gdb) back
#0  0x00007fffef3905f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fffef391ce8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fffefeb1515 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
   from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007fffefeaf6a6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007fffefeaf6d3 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff296a103 in ns3::BridgeNetDevice::AddBridgePort (this=0x790960,
    bridgePort=...) at ../src/bridge/model/bridge-net-device.cc:251
#6  0x00007ffff2974af4 in ns3::BridgeHelper::Install (this=0x7fffffffd090,
    node=..., c=...) at ../src/bridge/helper/bridge-helper.cc:56
#7  0x0000000000415b29 in simular (resultado=0x7fffffffdbf0,
    velocidades=std::map with 1 elements = {...}, observador=0x688ad0,
    telef1=100, telef2=100) at ../scratch/simvoip/simvoip.cc:297
#8  0x00000000004130df in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe1d8)
    at ../scratch/simvoip/simvoip.cc:126
```

Mil gracias de antemano por cualquier respuesta, sé que es un tema muy concreto y es bastante complicado resolverlo.

La foto con el planteamiento del escenario, por si sirve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo unico que faltaria en este escenario serían los bridge's entre Router's y teléfonos